# Why my text in a fit node is not vertically centered?

Tags: tikz-pgf, fit

I have the following abstracted code. I do not know why the text `test` is not centered. Do you know how to make it centered?

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, math, fit, backgrounds}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [draw = black] {A TEST};
\coordinate (a) at (current bounding box.south east); \draw (a) circle (3pt);
\coordinate (b) at ([yshift = -15 pt]current bounding box.south west);
\node (MEM) [inner sep = 0, fit = (a) (b), fill=black!20!red] {test};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

**Result:**

Please focus on the arrows I added manually.
[image]

Comment: The title of your question seems to contradict what you want to achieve. I wonder if you want to change it to ""why is my text in a fit node not centered".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is the predefined behavior of Ti*k*Z, please see section 52 of the pgfmanual. You can place "test" in the center of the node by putting another node at the center of the MEM node.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, math, fit, backgrounds}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [draw = black] {A TEST};
\coordinate (a) at (current bounding box.south east); \draw (a) circle (3pt);
\coordinate (b) at ([yshift = -15 pt]current bounding box.south west);
\draw (b) circle (3pt);
\node (MEM) [inner sep = 0, fit = (a) (b), fill=black!20!red] {};
\node (test) at (MEM.center){test};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

In a "fited" node the text baseline is put at the center of the node. If you want your text to be vertically centered, you can use `label=center:Test` like this

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=7pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node [draw = black] {A TEST};
    \coordinate (a) at (current bounding box.south east); \draw (a) circle (3pt);
    \coordinate (b) at ([yshift = -15 pt]current bounding box.south west);
    \node (MEM) [inner sep = 0, fit = (a) (b), fill=black!20!red, label = center:Test]{};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]